# Crossvalidation with R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am using an  R package called PEC to use together with coxph regression models. In estimating the C-index (area under the curve) I can use cross-validation and bootstrapping to validate the true C-index which is great. However, I have to supply an already trained model! How can I train and evaluate the model simultaneously? I wish to use the entire dataset with cv to train and evaluate the area under the curve to get the most reliable estimate, but if I use all the data in training I will only measure overfit during evaluation.

Comment: Which function are you using from the pec package? You can't cross validate without setting some of the data aside I'm afraid. However, the greater the number of folds you use if you do k-fold cross validation the less data you need to set aside, to a point.

Comment: It's the cindex() function. I understand that I must set some data aside; but the coxph model is fitted on ALL data, while crossvalidation is used for untrained models and trains them on overlapping portions of data and validates them on non-overlapping portions of data. But if the models is already fitted, why use CV? The fitting and CV should be done as one.